# Building and testing HTML5 application on Android Emulator in Eclipse

Tags: android, html

I have been scouring the web for hours trying to find a way to simply "test" a local HTML5 file on the Android Emulator but it seems to be a ridiculously difficult thing to do. On a Mac for iPhone you simply have a iPhone emulator in which you type in your

```
 localwebsite/page.hml
```

but what happens with Android?

I have the latest Android SDK updater and the SDK Android tools on eclipse but the only options are with actual Android applications, not web based ones.

Isn't there a browser plugin or Android browser equivalent to which we can add the Virtual Devices Packages?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Run "[android](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/android.html)" from your android SDK installation or run it from the "Android SDK and AVD Manager..." menu in Eclipse.  This lets you set up one or more AVD (Android Virtual Device) profiles. Once you've created one, you can select it and choose "start" to start it.

The next part depends on what you mean by "local" in this question -

If you mean "local" on the android device, you'll need to use "[adb](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/adb.html#copyfiles)" to copy the files into the "sdcard" area of the android filesystem.  Then open the android browser and load the file via "file:///sdcard/name_of_your_file.html".

If you mean "local" on your development machine, you'll need to put the file into the web server of your choice on your development box, then load it via "http://local.ip.address:port/name_of_your_file.html" in the android browser.

Comment: Thank you for answering my question. I am now trying to launch it with the start command but it is giving me the following error/msg:


"invalid command-line parameter: Files.
Hint: use '@foo' to launch a virtual device named 'foo'.
please use -help for more information"

I am not sure what this means. Do I need a device name in order to launch it? I meant local as in http://localhost/ but I don't see how/where I can navigate to that with the emulator.

Comment: @Chimp - "invalid command-line parameter: Files." This means that you have the Android SDK installed (and/or your AVD file saved) under "C:\Program *Files*\..." and the space in the path is messing it up.  Calling it "localhost" still doesn't clear the issue up... on the android device, "localhost" would be the device itself.